# Java, Generics and Classe<Generic> problems

Tags: java, generics, playframework, ebean

Here's my Model's parent :

```
abstract public class ApiModel {
    // Problem 1
    public static ExpressionList<Model> find() {
        return null;
    }
    
    public static <T extends Model> T findById(Long id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

A Model :

```
public class MyModel extends ApiModel {

    private static Model.Finder<Long,MyModel> find = new Model.Finder(Long.class, MyModel.class);

    public static ExpressionList<MyModel> find() {
        return find.where();
    }
    
    public static MyModel findById(Long id) {
        return find.byId(id);
    }
}
```

The parent's Controller :

```
public class ApiController<T extends ApiModel> extends Controller {
    public Result list() {
            // Problem 2
        ExpressionList<T> list = T.find();
        return ok(Json.toJson(list.orderBy("name"), 10));
    }
    
    public Result create() {
        return update(null);
    }
    
    public Result details(Long id) {
            // Problem 3
        T model = T.findById(id);
        
        // ...
        return ok(result);
    }
    
    public Result update(Long id) {
            // Problem 4
        Form<T> form = form(T.class).bindFromRequest();

            T model = form.get();

            // Problem 5
            T.save();

        // ...
        return ok(result);
    }
    
    public Result delete(Long id) {
        // ...
        return ok(result);
    }
}
```

A Controller

```
public class AController extends ApiController<MyModel> {
    public final static AController rest = new AController();
    
    private AController() {}
}
```

The problems I face :

1. I would need `find()` to returns `ExpressionList<T extends Model>`, but if I put this, I have an error.
2. Pb1 make this errors appears, it says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ExpressionList to ExpressionList". I suppose by fixing 1., 2. will be fixed also.
3. This one is odd, it returns "Bound mismatch: The generic method findById(Long) of type ApiModel is not applicable for the arguments (Long). The inferred type T&Model is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter "
4. Of course I can't use `.class` of this one. But how can I do then ?
5. Since the model use annotation to have `@Entity`, I can't use it here, it's not recognized :/

I think everything is related. Maybe I poorly designed my code ?

Here's the reason of that kind of structure. I'm using PlayFramework (that have static controllers) and I like to do inheritance and thus generic models. But for that, I need instance and not static reference, thus the `public final static AController rest`. But then, I can't access static context of the Model (`find` & `findById`). So I made ApiModel. But it doesn't help more either.

Comment: Is it normal that ``MyModel`` does not extend ``Model``?

Comment: No, it's an error from me. I'll fix it! :) Oh! With your comment, you fixed the problem 5 :) (Note: It's ApiModel that must extends Model)

Comment: I updated my code regarding the progress I made, there is only one problem left :)

Comment: (For the record, I rolled this question back to the version that Benoit would have seen when they answered it. Although clarifications to questions are permitted and encouraged, wholesale amendments to a question are discouraged if they would make an answer seem irrelevant or nonsensical. Where such an edit is desired, it should be done in a post-script or a new question, depending on the scale of the additional problem.)

Comment: (As an aside, multi-part questions of these kind are generally closed on Stack Overflow these days, for this reason - if someone answers only one point, is that a valid answer? Are two poor sub-answers more worthy of a tick-acceptance than one good sub-answer?)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `ApiModel` class if your rewrite a little `ApiController`:

```
public class ApiController<T extends Model> extends Controller {

    private Model.Finder<Long,T> finder;

    private final Class<T> modelClass;

    public ApiController(Class<T> modelClass) {
        this.modelClass = modelClass;
        finder = new Model.Finder(Long.class, modelClass);
    }

    public Result list() {
        ExpressionList<T> list = finder.where();
        return ok(Json.toJson(list.orderBy("name"), 10));
    }

    public Result details(Long id) {
        T model = finder.findById(id);

        // ...
        return ok(result);
    }

    public Result update(Long id) {
        // Problem 1
        Form<T> form = form(modelClass).bindFromRequest();

            T model = form.get();

            T.save();

        // ...
        return ok(result);
    }

    ...
}

public class AController extends ApiController<MyModel> {
    public final static AController rest = new AController();

    private AController() {
        super(MyModel.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I do `MyModel extends ApiModel<MyModel>`, I got : "Bound mismatch: The type MyModel is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Model> of the type ApiModel<T>"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need those static methods in `ApiModel`.

You should be able to endow `ApiController` with the `Class` for `T`.

```
public class ApiController<T extends ApiModel> extends Controller {
    private final Class<T> tClass;
    ApiController(Class<T> tClass) {
        this.tClass = tClass;
    }

public class AController extends ApiController<MyModel> {
    ....
    private AController() {
        super(MyModel.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it should be a bad idea to do that. You can use normal methods in play, you just need to reference the method in the route list with a `@` in the beginning.

So, if you have a controller this way:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    public Result index() {
        return TODO;
    }
}
```

You can use like this in your routers:

```
GET         /           @controllers.MyController.index()
```